# Calculate integrals 2

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to calculate this integrals

$$I_1 = \int _0^2\:\frac{\arctan \left(x\right)}{x^2+2x+2}dx$$
$$I_2 = \lim _{n\to \infty }\int _0^n\:\frac{\arctan x}{x^2+x+1}dx$$

I have a hint on the first one, the substitution $x = \frac{2-t}{1+2t}$, but I can't understand how it was conceived.

Comment: for $|ab|<1$, $\displaystyle \arctan(a)+\arctan(b)=\arctan\left(\tfrac{a+b}{1-ab}\right)$

Comment: @FDP How can I use this ?

Comment: Perform your change of variable and apply this formula from the right to the left.

Comment: @FDP The thing is I don't understand why that change should be done. Someone gave me that hint and I don't understand how he thought of it.

Comment: if you perform a change of variable to simplify the denominator you would make the argument of arctan(x) more difficult to deal with. But if you could write this arctan stuff as a sum of arctan(x) and arctan(constant) you earn something most of the time.

Comment: Other reason is, with your change of variable $\dfrac{1}{x^2+2x+2}dx=-\dfrac{1}{t^2+2t+2}dt$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\begin{align}
I_2=\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x^2+x+1}dx=\int_0^{1} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x^2+x+1}dx+\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x^2+x+1}dx
\end{align}$

In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$,

$\begin{align}
I_2&=\int_0^{1} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x^2+x+1}dx+\int_0^{1} \dfrac{\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2+x+1}dx\\
&=\int_0^{1} \dfrac{\left(\arctan x+\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)\right)}{x^2+x+1}dx\\
&=\int_0^{1} \dfrac{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}{x^2+x+1}dx\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{1}  \dfrac{1}{\left(x+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\tfrac{3}{4}}dx\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\times \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan\left(\tfrac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_0^1\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\arctan(\sqrt{3})-\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}-\dfrac{\pi}{6})\right)\\
&=\boxed{\dfrac{\pi^2}{6\sqrt{3}}}
\end{align}$

Other important relation for arctan function:

If $x>0$ then,

$\arctan x+\arctan\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

If $x<0$ replace $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ by $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

And remember too that, for all $x$ real,

$\arctan(-x)=-\arctan(x)$

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and also the the relations for $\arctan$ !

Comment: i have left behind I_1 that is more harder to deal with but you have a road map to compute it. Just follow it.

Comment: Very clever solution. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

In $I_1$ apply the change of variable $x=\dfrac{2-t}{1+2t}$,

Observe that $t=\dfrac{2-x}{1+2x}$,

$\begin{align}I_1=\int_0^2 \dfrac{\arctan\left(\tfrac{2-t}{1+2t}\right)}{t^2+2t+2}dt
\end{align}$

If $t\in [0;2[$ then $0<2t< 1$ therefore,

$\begin{align}I_1=\int_0^2 \dfrac{\arctan(2)}{t^2+2t+2}dt-I_1
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$\begin{align}I_1&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^2 \dfrac{\arctan(2)}{t^2+2t+2}dt\\
&=\dfrac{\arctan(2)}{2}\Big[\arctan\left(x+1\right)\Big]_0^2\\
&=\boxed{\dfrac{\arctan(2)\arctan(3)}{2}-\dfrac{\arctan(2)}{8}\pi}
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you for solving this too ! This is a multiple choice problem and I have to get to the answer $\frac{1}{2} \arctan 2 \cdot \arctan \frac{1}{2}$, how could I rewrite your answer ?

Comment: Probably you have to omit the last line of my computation of $I_1$ and use the addition formula for arctan i have mentionned above. (i haven't yet tried to get your result)

Comment: There is no absolute value in the arctan addition formula the condition is $ab<1$

Comment: Anyway if you had to decide if it's the good unique answer a good approximation is enough to decide. No need to get a closed form/exact value.

Comment: Yes, I would have guessed from the choices anyway in the end

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2}{\arctan\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 2x + 2}\,\dd x & =
\Im\int_{0}^{2}{\ln\pars{1 + x\ic} \over x^{2} + 2x + 2}\,\dd x\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{set}\ t = 1 + \ic x \implies x = \bracks{1 - t}\ic~}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\int_{\ic}^{1 + 2\ic}{\ln\pars{t} \over
\pars{t + \ic}\pars{t - 2 + \ic}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\int_{\ic}^{1 + 2\ic}{\ln\pars{t} \over -\ic - t}\,\dd t -
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\int_{\ic}^{1 + 2\ic}{\ln\pars{t} \over 2 - \ic - t}\,\dd t
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> However,

\begin{align}
\int{\ln\pars{t} \over z - t}\,\dd t & \,\,\,\stackrel{\tau\ =\ t/z}{=}\,\,\,
\int{\ln\pars{z\tau} \over 1 - \tau}\,\dd\tau =
-\ln\pars{1 - \tau}\ln\pars{z\tau} +
\int{\ln\pars{1 - \tau} \over \tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{1 - \tau}\ln\pars{z\tau} - \,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\tau} =
\bbx{\ds{-\ln\pars{1 - {t \over z}}\ln\pars{t} -
\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{t \over z}}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

With \eqref{2}, \eqref{1} becomes
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2}{\arctan\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 2x + 2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\left\lbrack%
-\ln\pars{1 - {1 + 2\ic \over -\ic}}\ln\pars{1 + 2\ic} -
\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 + 2\ic \over -\ic} +
\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over -\ic}\right.
\\[5mm] &\left.\phantom{=} +
\ln\pars{1 - {1 + 2\ic \over 2 - \ic}}\ln\pars{1 + 2\ic} +
\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 + 2\ic \over 2 - \ic} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2 - \ic}\right]
\\[1cm] & =
{1 \over 8}\bracks{\pi -4\,\mrm{arccot}\pars{3}}\arctan\pars{2} -
{1 \over 8}\,\ln^{2}\pars{5} -
\,{1 \over 2}\,\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-2 + \ic} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}
\\[5mm] & \phantom{=}+
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\ic} -
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{2 + \ic \over 5}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{{1 \over 8}\bracks{\pi -4\,\mrm{arccot}\pars{3}}\arctan\pars{2} -
{1 \over 8}\,\ln^{2}\pars{5} -\,{\pi^{2} \over 48} -
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-2 + \ic} -
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{2 + \ic \over 5}}}
\\[5mm] &\
\approx 0.2567
\end{align}